# Adding linear layout 2 to linear layout 1

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to add linearlayout 2 ["secondrow"] to linearlayout 1["firstrow"] but it throws an exception
The specified child has already a  parent you must call removeview() on child parent first.linearlayout1, linearlayout 2 ,linearlayout 3,linearlayout 4 has 4 buttons each.My java code is below

----------------------------Java code--------------------------

```
    private LinearLayout linearfirstRow;
        private LinearLayout linearsecondRow;
        private LinearLayout linearthirdRow;
        private LinearLayout linearfourthRow;
        private LinearLayout TemporaryLayout;
        linearfirstRow=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.firstrow);
        linearsecondRow=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.secondrow);
        linearthirdRow=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.thirdrow);
        linearfourthRow=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.fourththrow);
              TemporaryLayout=linearsecondRow;
                            linearfirstRow.removeAllViews();
                            linearsecondRow.removeAllViews();
          Throws error ---> linearfirstRow.addView(TemporaryLayout);
```

---

```xml
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                     <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Medium Text"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                           <LinearLayout
             firstrow-->   android:id="@+id/firstrow"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp" 
                        android:layout_weight="25"
                         >
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn1"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text="1"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn2"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text="1"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn3"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text="1"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn4"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text="1"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />
                    </LinearLayout>
         secondrow-->       <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/secondrow"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="25"
                         >

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn5"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text="2"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn6"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text="2"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn7"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text="2"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn8"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text="2"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/thirdrow"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"  
                        android:layout_weight="25" >

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn9"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text="3"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn10"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text="3"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn11"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text="3"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn12"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text="3"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/fourththrow"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"  
                        android:layout_weight="25">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn13"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text="4"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn14"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text="4"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn15"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text="4"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn16"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text="4"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to detach   `TemporaryLayout/linearsecondRow` from its parent linearlayout first i.e

```
        private LinearLayout linearfirstRow;
        private LinearLayout linearsecondRow;
        private LinearLayout linearthirdRow;
        private LinearLayout linearfourthRow;
        private LinearLayout TemporaryLayout;
        linearfirstRow=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.firstrow);
        linearsecondRow=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.secondrow);
        linearthirdRow=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.thirdrow);
        linearfourthRow=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.fourththrow);
              TemporaryLayout=linearsecondRow;
                            linearfirstRow.removeAllViews();
                            linearsecondRow.removeAllViews();

//Add this although i dont know why the above two lines were used by you   
        ((LinearLayout)TemporaryLayout.getParent()).removeView(TemporaryLayout);
        linearfirstRow.addView(TemporaryLayout);
```